# Регулярные выражения вернуть вхождение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть ли функция, которая возвращает вхождение по регулярному выражению?
Есть строка "100 комната 5", следующее регулярное выражение найдет в это строке число "100"

```
[0-9]+
```

Мне нужно, что функция вернула мне значение 100.

Comment: Вы ищете `preg_match` или что?

Comment: фух, да спасибо, не обратил внимание, что ее третий параметр делает то что мне и нужно

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам надо проверить строку, то можно использовать `preg_match`.

```
$str = "100 комната 5";
preg_match('/(\d+)/', $str, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

В ответе Вы получаете массив

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "100" 
    [1]=> string(3) "100" 
}
```

.

А если Вам надо проверить и занести найденное в переменную, то быстрее воспользоваться `preg_replace()`

```
$str = "100 комната 5";
$t = preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+).*?$/', '$1', $str);
var_dump($t);
```

Тогда `$t` будет `string(3) "100"`